# Correct form of verb after "I wish"

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood

What is correct form:

> I wish I *were* a king.

or

> I wish I *was* a king.

I need some explanation.

Comment: There are some great answers on the linked duplicate. Also interesting to note is that subjunctive is much more common in American English than in British English.

Comment: yes i have found some references

Comment: Mostly you find: I wish I were* dead (were* subjunctive) / I wish father were* here. - The subjunctive can be replaced by "was" as a substitute of the subjunctive. In the subclause you can also use "would": I wish you wouldn't smoke. Or "could": I wish I could swim.